# On which criteria are some objects exported and some not?

Tags: data-export

When I go to "Export" in Salesforce, a list of objects which can be exported is available. Which rule do those objects follow? i.e. which properties does a Salesforce objects have which then make it available for export?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide an answer. Please update your question to include as much detail as possible otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: @BarCotter better now?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the scheduled data exports, there is a list of objects on that page that you can choose from. There is also a button that allows you to select all data.

One thing to watch out for is that it doesn't take custom settings data.